# Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0, 0) (grub resolution)

Tags: grub2, display-resolution

I have tried to change ubuntu resolution via grub and just after i did -update grub, this error came up. Since i am very new with ubuntu, i have no idea yet how to solve it.

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0, 0)
```

Thanks

Marius

Comment: How exactly did you *tried to change ubuntu resolution via grub*?